# How to hide timezone option in kendo scheduler event creation in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, timezone, kendo-scheduler

When i unchecked 'All Day Event' option in 'Kendo' scheduler event, its giving timezone option. How can i  hide that timezone option?

-

Comment: Can you attach an image of what you mean or build a demo in Plunker?

Answer (score 0):

The timezone options are implemented in a separate kendo.timezones.min.js file. If you remove it from your page declaration you will not have the timezone option and the default "Etc/UTC" timezone will be used.